# Example use of tensorflow-serving for image segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, tensorflow-serving

Has anyone worked on a template example of how to use tensorflow serving for an image segmentation task?

Appreciate if you can share code or share some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008) is an explanation of how to publish and consume a model for images through TensorFlow Serving with Docker and HTTP. The client side is identical without Docker. You can find the code the post uses [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/serving/master/tensorflow_serving/example/resnet_client.py).

Basically you have to POST to `http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}:predict` with a JSON with the format `{"instances" : [{"b64": <image_in_jpg_in_base64>}]}`. You can learn more about TF Serving RESTful API [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest).